# Normalize county coverage data by population

Tags: qgis, point, count, normalize

I have point data where the result is either in coverage or out of coverage. I know that we receive far more in coverage results in high population areas, so I want to normalize the data by population. Everything is by county, so I have, for example, Florida - Pinellas - 15 in coverage - 0 out of coverage - population 982705, and I have this for every county in the US. I want to create a choropleth map of the entire US with the coverage represented normalized by population.

I need to do this using QGIS.

Comment: You can use field calculator to calculate a new field, say coverage/population. `Toggle Edit` on your layer then open `Attributes Table> Field Calculator` and add `"in coverage"/"population"` in the expression field. For choropleth map, you need to join the point layer with a polygon layer of counties and then make graduated symbology. Try this out and ask if you face any specific problem.

Comment: What is coverage?

Comment: What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Thanks @Abhijith this worked.